$8$-th power in quadratic extesion of $\mathbb{Q}_p$
Problem: Show that $16$ is an $8$-th power in the field $\mathbb{Q}_p(\sqrt{7})$ for all $p$.
What I have done: For $p$ odd, I can just look at the polynomial $x^8-16$ and use Hensel's lemma to verify that this polynomial always has a simple root modulo $p$, hence gives rise to a root in $\mathbb{Z}_p$.
However, I stuck for $p=2$. Since $x^8-16 = (x^4+4)(x^2+2)(x^2-2)$, I reduced the problem to show that either $\pm 2$ is a square in $\mathbb{Q}_p(\sqrt{7})$ or $-4$ is a $4$-th power. Now if $ c = (a+b\sqrt{7})^2$ $-$ where $c$ is an element of $\mathbb{Q}_2$ $-$ it implies that $a=0$ or $b=0$. Now consider $$(a+b\sqrt{7})^2 = c, \quad c \in \left\lbrace \pm 2,-4\right\rbrace$$
I then reduced to solve for either $a^2 = c$ or $7b^2 = c$. This means either $c$ or $c/7$ is a square in  $\mathbb{Q}_2$.  Now use the fact that a square in  $\mathbb{Q}_2$ must have the form $p^{2n}u$ for $ u \equiv 1 \pmod 8$, the equation $a^2 =c$ has no roots. On the other hand $1/7 \equiv -1 \pmod 8$, thus the only equation that may have roots is $7b^2=-4$. But I need $-4$  to be a $4$th-power, not just a square, and I have no idea how to verify this.
I would be very grateful if someone could provide some hint or point out if I made mistakes somewhere above in the argument. Thank you.

Note that $\Bbb Q_2(\sqrt{7})=\Bbb Q_2(\sqrt{-1})$. Now $(1+\sqrt{-1})^2=2\sqrt{-1}$, so $(1+\sqrt{-1})^8=16$.
